# Liste de mots en français avec type

Tags: dictionnaires

Je cherche une liste des mots français, qui donnerait également le type de chaque mot (nom commun, adjectif, verbe, etc.). Cette liste peut contenir les déclinaisons des mots (comme les listes que l'on trouve facilement sur internet, utilisées pour le scrabble ou les mots croisés), mais ce n'est pas nécessaire -- je cherche plus quelque chose qui s'apparente aux entrées d'un dictionnaire (sans définitions).

Si une même orthographe correspond à plusieurs types différents (droit (n.c)/droit (adj.)), idéalement cette liste comporterait une ligne pour chaque.

Existe-t-il une telle liste de disponible pour un usage privé?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu trouveras je pense ton bonheur dans la base librement accessible [Lexique](http://www.lexique.org/), qui contient 140 000 mots.

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre l'achitecture de cette base. Par exemple "maison" n'a pas de genre associé alors que "maisons" au pluriel est bien marqué comme féminin. Penses-tu que quelque chose d'aussi évident puisse être un bug dans la base? Ou bien je n'ai pas compris comment elle est organisée?

Comment: @user209974 Curieux. Les genres sont fournis par Cordial Analyseur 8 qui est plutôt fiable. Peut-être que c'est l'utilisation de *maison* au masculin dans une phrase comme *J'en prends un maison* (pour un cocktail maison, par exemple) qui explique cette épicénéité inattendue. Lexique un projet collaboratif et il y a un [groupe Google](https://groups.google.com/g/lexiqueorg) où on peut poser cette question.